# PHP Basic auth not working in xampp

Tags: php, codeigniter, basic-authentication

I am using `PHP Basic Authorization` but it's not working. The username and password pop-up as expected but it allows me to access the page even though I insert the wrong user and password

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) 
    {
        header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Area\"");
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        print "Sorry - you need valid credentials to be granted access!\n";
        exit;
    } else {
        list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
        if (!($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'admin') && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'admin')) {
            header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Area\"");
            header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
            print "Sorry - you need valid credentials to be granted access!\n";
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: Is the user put into session after he/she enters the credentials?

Comment: yes @Nurzhan ..

Comment: Your admin account must have "admin" for login and password ? , you should add bracket if (!(($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'admin') && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'admin')))

Comment: aaw thanks ! it's working fine in my localhost :) @Fky

Comment: @may you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing brackets, if you want "admin" for login and password you should do this:

```
if (!(($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'admin') && ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'admin'))) {
```